# in PHP how do i use range() for creating timing list?

Tags: php

i want to create a table where first column have timing  in below style

---

```
timing | user1 | user2 | user3
-------------------------------
9 AM   |       |       |
10 AM  |       |       |
.      |       |       |
.      |       |       |
.      |       |       |
6 PM   |       |       |
7 PM   |       |       |
```

is it possible to use `range()` for creating timing list, if yes then please tell me , or if not then suggest me better method.

**UPDATE:**
 when i use `range(strtotime('9 AM'),strtotime('7 PM'),86400)` it returns bool(false)
Thanks always. m i applying wrong way?

Comment: You are setting yourself up for a nightmare if you are expecting to come back later and use sql selects to extract valuable information from that table.

My advice would be that if you really have to set times in your table (and not dates and times?) then just use a the correct column type:

    "09:00:00"  etc

Then format with AM etc in your PHP logic as you display it.

(Just saying, its not an answer so adding it as a comment)

Comment: i m not extract value to mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do that with [`range`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) alone, but you can do

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
foreach(range(9,19) as $hour) {
    echo date('g A', $hour*3600);
}
```

which would give

```
9 AM 10 AM 11 AM 12 PM 1 PM 2 PM 3 PM 4 PM 5 PM 6 PM 7 PM
```

Your approach would work too, if you take one hour for step instead of one day:

```
range(strtotime('9 AM'), strtotime('7 PM'), 3600);
```

but keep in mind that it is much quicker to just have an an array with these values hardcoded somewhere instead of calculating them on the fly each time you need them.

And of course you can also use `DateInterval`. Have a look around StackOverflow for examples.

Comment: yes, that i want exactly! thanks.... and i need these value on the fly, i m not gonna save it anywhere, thats y i want to create an array on the fly

Comment: can't we trail leading zero??

Comment: y u use -1 in `$hour*3600 -1` it display 8 AM to 6 PM then.

Comment: i"ll use hardcore, okay sir,
but just for enrich my knowledge i want to do thing in easy way.

Comment: Thanks Gordon sir, please use `echo` outside of `ltrim`

Comment: @I Like PHP sorry, was my fault. I forgot the time would be evaluated to my timezone, which is GMT+1, so I had to do -1 to get the right time. See above, using `date` will give the exact result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how range() can be used here.
I'd suggest to use mktime+date in the loop, to increment time by 1 hour and format it with am pm format.